# Problem regarding Edit Text Boxes focus change ( Seen other questions .. they exactly rnt helping )

Tags: android, focus

I have total of 9 Edit text boxes now i have implemented on focuschangelistener on each one of them. But now while moving through the boxes i want to pick up the id othe Edit Text Box on which the pointer is currently present.

The focuschangelistener works only when the focus is shifted .. now suppose cursor is poiniting at the sixth box .. so i want a API which could tell me me at the background that which Box is currently in use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [getCurrentFocus()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getCurrentFocus%28%29) method in Activity.

Comment: On what do i have to imlement this method.
Kindly tell that too, becaue i dnt think this method is to implemented on edittext boxes

Comment: You don't have to implement the method, use this method to get the currently focused view in the Activity, and check its id to see which edit box is focused.